# Sorting awk results into multiple files based on value ranges

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following data, potentially spread across multiple input files:

```
colB1:colB2:colB3:$130.00:...
colC1:colC2:colC3:$83.00:...
colD1:colD2:colD3:$80.00:...
```

My goal is to write the first two columns from each line of input into an output file whose name contains the number beginning a $10 range.

Thus, for the above input, I would have two output files, one with two lines, the other with one:

```
balance-80.out
===
colC1:colC2
colD1:colD2

balance-130.out
===
colB1:colB2
```

---

My current attempt looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((value_1=90; value_1<200; value_1+=10)); do
   awk -F: \
     -v var=$value_1 \
     -v var1=$((value_1+10)) \
     '{ sub(/\$/, "", $4) }
      ($4+0) >= var && ($4+0) < var1 { print $1":"$2 }' \
     *.txt > balance_$value_1.txt
done
```

This works, but it's obviously very kludgy. How could this be done in a single pass?

Comment: Why don't you start by building an MCVE and fixing the obvious bugs that *aren't* related to `awk`? For instance, `$value_1=90` doesn't assign to a variable `value_1` at all.

Comment: ...frankly, the question you were linked to as a duplicate *does* describe bugs that are present in your script. If you fix those bugs and still have a problem, then this'll be a good place to help you -- but fix all the other problems first, so that the *only* bug present in your script is the specific bug that the question is intended to be about.

Comment: what is MCVE google returns credit card software?

Comment: (Also, @-notices inside of question text aren't communicated to the person they're directed to, so your edits aren't exceptionally likely to get through to their intended recipient. You already have more than 50 reputation -- aren't you allowed to use the comment system?)

Comment: A MCVE is a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is: It has the smallest possible amount of code to show the problem you're asking about; it's complete and correct enough to actually show that problem when run; and other people can use it to verify the issue without needing to do extra work (creating files, etc).

Comment: I was modifying this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828225/increment-in-bash-loop-by-set-amount

Comment: Noted. You still have some pretty major outstanding bugs -- see http://shellcheck.net/ for automated detection of some of them.

Comment: so, bluntly: Why in the world are you doing it this way? What's the point of `for counter in {90..200}; do` instead of `for ((value_1=90; value_1<200; value_1+=10)); do`, for instance?

Comment: i was just modifying the script as stated, and it had it in there, i mentioned that i am amateur.

Comment: ...anyhow. With the fixes you've done, the most obvious bugs that are still outstanding are related to needing to pass shell variables into awk correctly. @hek2mgl closed this as a duplicate of a question about passing shell variables into awk, and that's exactly what your problem is, so I have to call the close-as-dupe action correct. Follow the link, leverage the advice given on the other end.

Comment: ...quick hint: `[[ $value_1 = end ]]` is not `[[ $value_1 = $end ]]`.

Comment: ...also, `var1=$value_1+=10` is also almost certainly not what you want -- it's passing a string like `90+=10`, not a value like `100`. `var1=$((value_1+10))` is, at minimum, not as obviously wrong.

Comment: i'm doing the best i can here..

Comment: Consider running `bash -x yourscript` to run the script logging each command that's run -- that way you can see the difference between, well, `90+=10` and `100`.

Comment: that said, this is getting better -- it's much closer to being a quality question ripe for reopening. I'm guessing the real question might be "Only emitting an output file from awk when contents exist", maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the `bash -x yourscript` advice...

Comment: no, there is still something wrong with my awk, as the very first result contains all 3 results, and the next increments are outputting ok.. (i'll get it)

Comment: BTW, it's generally speaking a bad idea to use an output filename form that your input filename glob also matches -- doing so means that if you run your script more than once you can get different results. Consider naming your output files `*.out` instead of `*.txt` so you can't mistakenly process them as input.

Comment: thanks, for the tip about .out i'm gonna pick up a bash book as well as awk..

Comment: When I run this with the exact input file you provide in your question (and no `balance_*.txt` files to confuse things), I get one line in `balance_90.txt` and one line in `balance_130.txt`. That behavior looks correct to me for this input. If there are bugs, could you consider making sure that the input file you include in the question exercises those bugs?

Comment: ...btw, if you're looking for a reliable reference, the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is a good place to start.

Comment: (...all that said, if I were writing this myself, I'd probably have it run awk just once, and have the awk code be responsible for splitting into multiple output files -- much more efficient than running awk once per range).

Comment: I think all i need to do now is add an if statement for $4 value around the awk.. I know mostly basic and not so much gnu stuff.  Ha! with my skillset, feel free to post an example code of running awk once ;)

Comment: yes, no values below 90, the buckets need to be every $10 from 90 onwards to 200.

Comment: frankly, if you know how to do that, might I suggest leaving it out of the question spec? Making the spec as small and focused as possible on the parts you don't understand how to do on your own is part of the **M** ("minimal") in MCVE.

Comment: well, its all working now, thanks, i just need to figure out how to only write to file if field $4 is between the min max values..

Comment: `($4+0) >= var && ($4+0) < var1` *is* a condition. Comparing `$4` to your min and max values is exactly what it does already, as it is -- and when I run your code with the sample data you provided, it works perfectly. Maybe your real data is different?

Comment: yes, the code is working great, thanks for all the help. I know that awk is writing empty files, as per code, i'm just trying to figure out how to only write a file only if min max $ value is there.. so there are not a bunch of empty files

Comment: If you're going to use shell redirection to put content into output files, you'll need to follow behind after-the-fact and delete the empty ones -- you can't prevent their creation in the first place because the output file is created *before* `awk` is invoked, so whether it'll be empty or not isn't known until after it's created. That following behind is easy to do, though -- `[ -s "$filename" ] || rm -f "$filename" `, for instance. Or, more efficiently, you can do the single-pass thing with `awk` creating the files rather than the shell doing so -- see my answer.

Comment: can't i output the awk result to a variable instead of a file? and add an if statement after the awk..like if variable != 0 then cat > variable or something?

Comment: Sure, you can, but then you're constraining the size of your output files to what'll fit in memory. I'm not about to presume that kind of constraint without it being a given. :)

Comment: `var=$(awk ...); [[ $var ]] && printf '%s\n' "$var" >file` is what that would actually look like.

Comment: alright, now i'm gonna find some bash, awk, sed Videos & eBooks, and really get down and learn this properly.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: not to mention regex!!

Comment: Be careful about the learning materials you choose -- there are a lot of folks who do bash badly, and unfortunately, even a fair number of folks who *teach* bash badly. I've previously recommended the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) -- also see the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) as another resource that tends to be well-maintained. Steer clear of the ABS -- it tends to showcase bad examples.

Comment: (off-topic) +100 for @CharlesDuffy for your enormous efforts to help here. I'm impressed.

Comment: yep, wish i could donate all my points to him..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points:

- You can create output files from `awk` -- and high-quality `awk` implementations will cache file descriptors automatically, thus keeping output files open between individual lines (which similar shell scripts won't do)
- Modulo arithmetic is the appropriate tool for selecting a filename as an appropriate bucket for any given value.

Thus:

```
awk -F: -v min=80 -v max=200 '
  { sub(/\$/, "", $4); val = (0 + $4) }
  val >= min && val < max {
    print $1 ":" $2 >("balance-" (val - (val % 10)) ".out")
  }
' *.txt
```